# Noun clause or an adjective clause?

Tags: subordinate-clauses

Our professor told us that the following sentence contains a noun clause, because it tells an idea about "the story" and does not modify it.

> The story **that the beach would be closed** filled her with fear.

Is this correct or is it an adjective clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your teacher is right. The clause does not describe (modify) *the story*; rather, it tells you what the story is. It is therefore not a relative (or adjective) clause functioning as a modifier, but a content (or noun) clause functioning as a complement.

Relative clauses differ syntactically from content clauses in that the former normally have a gap—a missing element which the relative referent could fill. Take a look at this sentence:

> I don't like the story (that) your dad is telling  __ to us.

Note that the direct object of the verb *TELL* is missing but we can safely assume the noun phrase *the story* tacitly realizes this function.